# Hiding panels from EasyUi tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-easyui

I have a easyui Tab with 4 tabs.

Depending on response from server I may have to hide/show some tabs. 
I tried the approach of removing the tabs at first and adding them later.But the problem is as the tabs are removed so as the DOM objects.So am not able to add the $("#") object later.

So better options is to hide/show the tabs .Is that possible in easyui tabs?

Answer (score 1):

just close the tabs that you don't want to show

```
$('#mytabs').tabs('close','titletab');
```